# Django crashes on the second form POST while creating a matplotlib.pyplot image from a pandas object

Tags: django, python-3.x, pandas, post

My Django program crashes with the following error:
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

... which is some kind of C error. My difficulty is debugging the stack - I don't know where to chase the problem.

`analysis` is a pandas DataFrame object

Here's the offending code that loads in Django in the index *View*:

```
def index(request):
    d = {'a': [0,1,2,3], 'b': [-2,5,3,0] }
    analysis = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    myImage = image(analysis)
    context = {'form': form, 'myImage': myImage }

def image(analysis):
    print('if this is the second POST, you will crash on running the next line')
    image = analysis.plot(x='a', y='b')
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    image = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
    return image
```

The form POST runs perfectly the *first* time. The second POST is the problem.

I can reproduce the error by doing the following:

1. User visits /
2. User fills in the form, selects his file and pushes submit
3. Form directs to / (the same URL) and loads with an image after analyzing a uploaded file
4. User changes the form fields, uploads a file (new or different doesn't matter), then pushes submit for the second time
5. The program crashes on running `image = analysis.plot(x='Indicator Value', y='Mean Period Return')` in `image()`

I made a little test program to run outside of Django, which is posted below. It runs flawlessly. It's only when I run this code in my Django View that everything crashes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io, base64   

d = {'a': [0,1,2,3], 'b': [-2,5,3,0] }
analysis = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def image(analysis):
    print('if this is the second POST, you will crash on running the next line')
    image = analysis.plot(x='a', y='b')
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    image = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
    return image 


myImage = image(analysis)
print('******\tmade image a')
myImage = image(analysis)
print('******\tmade image b')
```

Lastly, the crash page in my browser is not the usual Django debugger. Django exits, so the only page that I see is a connection reset page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I find out that there was a problem with the backend that matplotlib was using, to solve this, the recommended backend is Agg, and you should set this up before importing pyplot:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
```

You can find more documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server).